# iPhone Timer Picker

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, iphone-sdk-3.0

Is it possible to make this go as granular as seconds without having to write a custom picker?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to write a custom picker to enter seconds.

UIDatePicker is constrained to the following Date Picker Modes as defined in UIDatePicker, none of which displays seconds:

```
typedef enum {
   UIDatePickerModeTime,
   UIDatePickerModeDate,
   UIDatePickerModeDateAndTime,
   UIDatePickerModeCountDownTimer
} UIDatePickerMode;
```

Cheers, niels